# Finding an item months after getting it replaced by insurance

Tags: united-kingdom, insurance

Many months ago I lost my phone. It was insurred and I got it replaced. Earlier today I thought I found the old phone (it was actually a previous model of the same make of phone). For a brief few seconds I thought I had found the lost phone and I didn't really know what to do. Send it to the company that insurred it? Sell It? Bury it in the garden and pretend I didn't find it?

This brings me to a larger question; in general what is expected of me as a customer of insurance if I lose something and then find it months later?

Comment: Can you edit and add country tag

Comment: Almost certainly the legal thing is to inform them, as they would have claim to either the money they paid you, the replacement they sent, or the "lost" item. See [this article](https://www.insurancehotline.com/lost-and-found-what-happens-when-you-find-your-ring-after-submitting-a-claim/), [this conversation on Mumsnet](https://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/legal_money_matters/2526186-Found-lost-ring-6-months-after-claiming-on-insurance-do-I-declare-it) or [this article](http://www.riskafrica.com/lost-found-insurance-procedure-something-reappears/) (albeit for Africa).

Comment: I could see this getting out of hand quickly if you inform the company. Yes I think it might be taking advantage of your insurance, but as far as they are concerned it is over, by telling them now you could be opening yourself up to a bill for the full price of the phone, which depending on the phone, could be substantial. I like the idea of burying it in the garden.  IANAL though.

Comment: I would assume that the insurance company reported the serial number of the missing phone to the network provider, and could be notified should the phone appear in use again.

Answer (score 7):

You will have to look at the fine print on your insurance agreement, but the short answer is that any item that insurance pays a claim for becomes the property of the insurance company if ever recovered.

If you find a phone months later, you aren't obligated to tell them that it was your own negligence that lost the phone, but you are obligated to send them the recovered phone. It's actually reasonably common for lost or stolen items to be returned to their owners long enough after the time that they were lost for a claim to have already been processed. The insurance company should make arrangements for you to send in the old phone.